# Share path between server and client (delphi) application

Tags: delphi, share, lan

On my LAN I have 2 applications running in server/client mode developed with Delphi (but I don't think this is important).
On server PC (where run server application) there is a USB hard disk, this hard disk have many folder and subfolder shared on LAN.
Now I need to do this:
1. The server application must send to client application a shared folder (for example "d:\folder\subfolder\", then the client application must open this path to show the files (using explorer).
2. The user, using client application, must select a shared folder (for example "\SERVER\folder\subfolder\") and send this to server application, the server application must convert this path in local path (for example "d:\folder\subfolder\") and save it inside a database.

My problem is: is there a simple way to:
1. Convert the local path to remote path before send it to client se the client can open it easily?
2. Convert the remote path to local path before save it inside database.

NOTE: the main folder or main drive of shared hard disk can be change.
NOTE2: I'd like use IP address and not windows pc name if possible because it can be change.

I hope I explained.

Thanks

Comment: Normally IP addresses are more likely to change. Or do you want IP addresses because they can change? Also why do you have to store local paths? You can access unc names from both the server and the client.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to acces some files that are inside some shared folder. Right?

If that is true then go and acces to these files unsing the network path which is formed in this manner

```
\\Networkedcomputer\SharedFolderName\Subfolder\...
```

where:

- NetworkComputer is either a name of computer that is sharing that folder or its IP adress. I asume you are interested in using of IP adresses since you already have acces to that information from your other networked components.
- SharedFolderName is the network name that was chosen when specific filder was set to be shared on the network. This name doesen't even have to be the same as the name of actual folder
- Subolder can be any subfolder of the share folder

In order to get networked path to your shared folder you do need to know network name of the shared folder.

Perhaps you could even retrieve this information from SelectDirectory method which shows special dialog for selecting of directory, but I'm not sure if it does support networked folders. If not you could make use of OpenDialog.
NOTE: In any case when selecting the shared folder either with the use of SelectDirectory or OpenDialog you would need to go to that folder through Network Places (Network -> MyComputerName) and not directly through MyComputer.

But if you need to aquire the shared name for any local folder programatically I think you would have to go and read that information from registry as I'm not sure there is a specific API call for this.

EDIT: The answer on SO question below refers to several Delphi components that can be used for managing of Shared network resources. So I guess you could use to retrieve the network path for a shared local folder but I haven't tried them out.
[How do I remotely obtain a system's network shares and connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700381/how-do-i-remotely-obtain-a-systems-network-shares-and-connections/2700580#2700580)

Comment: The asker seems to ask how to convert a local path to a name that can be used on another machine. Your answer makes no attempt to address that.